# Freemarker nested list

Tags: java, freemarker

this works fine:

```
<#list myObjects as myObject>
  <tr>
    <td>${myObject.person.surname}</td>
    <td>${myObject.myListOfCountries[0].city.name}</td>
  </tr>
</#list>
```

However if I instead try to create a nested list like so, which does not work :

```
<#list myObjects as myObject>
  <tr>
    <td>${myObject.person.surname}</td>
    <#list myObject.myListOfCountries as item>
       <td>${item.city.name</td>
    </#list> 
  </tr>
</#list>
```

the error I receive is shown below :

```
freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered "/"
```

Any ideas what causes the error - are nested lists allowed in freemarker ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't closed your brace. It should be:

```
<td>${item.city.name}</td>
```

Comment: oh em gee. I was looking at that for about twenty mins, and even just asked my colleage. thankyou